# sql agent job does not show in log file

Tags: sql, sql-agent-job

I have an sql job (mssql 2008) that runs everyday at 04:00 and 16:00, today at 04:00 it did not run.  When I have viewed history on the job there is no entry for that time even to say it failed.

I ran the job manually and it worked fine.  So my question is does anyone know why there was no entry on this job in the view history section.  each time it has ran over the previous few weeks its been fine and there is always an entry reporting success.

Comment: That is the behavior you would see if your server was down, or the agent was stopped at the time the job was run.   Are you sure they were up?

Comment: it should, although your advice does help as I have noticed some other issues since logging the probelm.